# Meteor jumps to certain points on a page when visiting them for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

When I click a link that is routed with iron-router to a specific page template with meteor it skips to the very end of the page I am not sure what is causing this, I am using jquery waypoints, but i turned them off to test, still same problem, turned off all my css still same issue really not sure how to fix this. Take a look at the link [here](http://anderskitson.ca/) Click on the work link to see what I mean.

**Here is my router configuration.**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});
  this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
  this.route('postEdit', {
    path: '/posts/:_id/edit',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
  this.route('postSubmit', {
    path: '/submit'
  });
  this.route('signIn',{
    path:'/layout'
  });
  this.route('process',{
    path:'/process'
  });
  this.route('work',{
    path:'/work'
  });
});
var requireLogin = function(pause) {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn())
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    else
      this.render('accessDenied');
    pause();
  }
};

var scrollUp = function() {
  $('body').scrollTop(0);
};

Router.onBeforeAction(scrollUp);


Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'postSubmit'});
```

Comment: Add your router code and especially stuff you do on rendered for the work template - otherwise kinda hard to debug blindly.

Comment: I added my router configuration, the rendered javascript for the work template has all been commented out so I don't think its the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some Reason taking the id attribute out of the anchor tag that linked to the work page solved the issue.

From       `<li><a class="work" id="work"  href="work">work</a></li>`

to        `<li><a class="work"  href="work">work</a></li>`